# Submit event of a submit type input isn't triggered

Tags: javascript

I wrote a silly example to see which of the two, the `click` or the `submit` event, fires first on an input of type `submit`.

When I run it, though, nothing is written to the console.

Stepping through the code in the debugger reveals the following series of occurrences.

1. It fires the `click` event handler first, writes the text "click" to the console, but then shortly afterwards, the text disappears from the console.
2. Also, the `submit` event is never fired.

**I infer that the form is getting submitted after executing the `click` event of the button. The thing I don't understand is why it isn't getting into my `submit` event handler?**

Below is the relevant code, and here is [the full working example](https://github.com/Sathyaish/Practice/blob/master/JavaScript/Language/ClickOrSubmit.html). It's just a simple HTML file you can download and try out on your machine.

```js
(function() {
let btn = document.getElementById("btnSave");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
 console.log("click");
}, false);
btn.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
 console.log("submit");
 // event.preventDefault();
}, false);

console.log("All done now. Click da button, chum, click it I say!");

})();
```

```css
div { margin: 20px; }
input[type="submit"] { width: 200px; height: 50px; }
```

```html
<div>Look at the console and then click the button, chum!</div>

<div>
    <form>
        <input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Save" width="200px" />
    </form>            
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The thing I don't understand is why it isn't getting into my submit event handler?

`input` elements don't have a `submit` event. You need to hook `submit` on the `form`, not the `input`.

```
btn.form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
// ^^^^^
  console.log("submit");
  event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

(`btn.form` there could be `btn.closest("form")` if you prefer, though `btn.form` is more widely-supported and is (also) [standardized](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-fae-form). Or, of course, use `getElementById` or `querySelector` to retrieve the `form` element.)

Live Example:

```js
(function() {
  let btn = document.getElementById("btnSave");

  btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log("click");
  }, false);
  btn.form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  // ^^^^^
    console.log("submit");
    event.preventDefault();
  }, false);

  console.log("All done now. Click da button, chum, click it I say!");

})();
```

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>Look at the console and then click the button, chum!</div>

<div>
  <form>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Save" width="200px" />
  </form>
</div>
```